# AngularJS, how do I combine multiple inputs into a single ng-model? Specifically, to combine a date, time, and timezone input into a datetime object

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, forms, angular-ngmodel

I need to create a datetime object to store in MySQL, but I need it to be entered with multiple inputs (one for date, one for time, one for timezone). So right now my code is like this:

```
<input type="datetime-local", ng-model="workshop_date">
```

But what I want is something more like this:

```
 <input type="date", ng-model="date">
 <input type="time", ng-model="time">
 <select ng-model="zone">
     <option>Pacific</option>
     <option>Eastern</option>

 <input value='{{date + time + zone}}', ng-model="workshop_date", style="display:none">
```

However, this solution seems to confuse Angular. Is there any way I can take multiple inputs and make that the value of the ng-model?

Answer (score 4):

Something like that ?

**HTML**

```
<input type="date" ng-model="tmp.date">
<input type="time" ng-model="tmp.time">
<select ng-model="tmp.timezone">...</select>

<strong>{{ workshop_date }}</strong>
```

**Javascript**

```
// into controller
$scope.tmp = {
    date: '',
    time: '',
    timezone: ''
};

$scope.workshop_date = '';

$scope.$watch('[tmp.date, tmp.time, tmp.timezone]', function (tmp) {
    // you may need to add some logic here...
    $scope.workshop_date = date + time + zone;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

On way would be to use 3 distinct values and create a getter for workshop_date to get the concatenation of the 3 when requested and if using angular 1.3 you can also use ng-model-options.

```
<input type="date", ng-model="date">
<input type="time", ng-model="time">
<select ng-model="zone">
     <option>Pacific</option>
     <option>Eastern</option>
</select>
```

If you need a field display it (or even editing it)

```
<input ng-model="myObj.getWorkShopDate" ng-model-options="getterSetter: true">
```

And in your controller you can defined a getter/setter (or just getter)

```
$scope.myObj = {
    getWorkShopDate: function(value){
       if(value)
         // split into date,time,zone
       else
          return $scope.date + $scope.time + $scope.zone;
    }
}
```

here is the [official documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModel)  plnkr [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)